Describe what it feels like to you that two notes have the same pitch
In the process of training my very untrained hear, I wish to build on knowledge of what it is meant when we say two octaves are the same note.
I want to know what it feels when you play two notes one octave apart, either at once or in sequence, such that you can confidently say they are the same.
I understand that there are two components to this:

the measurable physical reason such as doubling of frequencies, spectrum of sound produced e.g. by the ringing of a piano string, decay of sound over time

the one related to how brain processes sound which encompasses things like timbre and attack.


I wish to know about how different physical aspects maps to the perception that two notes one octave apart 'sound the same'.
While the experience of this phenomenon has an element of subjectivity, I don't think this makes the question opinion based, as I reckon users experience constitute qualitative rather than quantitative data. I would also argue that, while experience is subjective, we all share a similar physical structure which bounds how widely different experiences could be.
Any pointer to papers with surveys about this phenomenon is also welcome.
Things I noticed of my own experience:

If I sing a note that matches the one I'm playing on the piano I get a sensation of fullness and resonance in my ears and mouth.

Playing two notes at once gives a sensation that they decay together and never grow apart, contrasted with two notes less than an octave apart, which feel like they separate over time.

Playing two notes in sequence, I can say quite confidently when two notes are not the same pitch, but I'm not always sure when they are the same.



I don't think my subjective experience of what an octave feels like, if I could even describe it, would help you recognize an octave, since you may have a different subjective experience of what an octave feels like.

To learn what an octave sounds like, you need to hear an octave paired with its "label" in some way many times.  An easy way to do this is to pick up a polyphonic instrument and play some octaves.  Another way would be online interval training drills.

That's what I'm doing, I'm just curious here and it might not help, but also..it might.

Btw, however people describe their subjective experience of octaves, there are objective (mathematical) reasons for them. I'd suggest editing to ask about this, to qualify for reopening. E.g. the "decay together" phenomenon is because their sound waves are in an exact 2 to 1 ratio and add to each other instead of canceling each other out.

Thank you, the objective ones seem fairly clear to me, but I don't really find it helpful at all in improving my hear, hence the question. Shame this is considered too opinion based (I can kinda see why but I think the question would be still interesting for many readers here)

I tried to motivate the q better, I feel now it might be too broad.

Good edits; I've voted to reopen. IMO it's not too broad since it might seem mysterious now but the reasons that different-octave versions of "the same" pitch sound "the same" are really pretty simple, and so are the acoustic results.

The question still needs work - currently you say you wish to survey users. That is explicitly off topic / opinion-based. I agree that the core of the question is answerable as per Andy's comment, but please edit it to a question asking for a single correct answer, not multiples

Further edited to account for this
